# Error in code using javascript

Tags: javascript

The code I have for my username and password verification is bringing up an error and im not sure how to fix it 
I am trying to use

```
function checkForm(form) {
    if (form.username.value == "") {
        alert("Error: Username cannot be blank!");
        form.username.focus();
        return false;
    }
    re = /^\w+$/;
    if (!re.test(form.username.value)) {
        alert("Error: Username must contain only letters, numbers and underscores!");
        form.username.focus();
        return false.pwd2.value) {
        if (form.pwd1.value.length < 8) {;
        }

        if (form.pwd1.value != "" && form.pwd1.value == form alert("Error: Password must contain at least eight characters!"); form.pwd1.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (form.pwd1.value == form.username.value) {
            alert("Error: Password must be different from Username!");
            form.pwd1.focus();
            return false;
        }
        re = /[0-9]/;
        if (!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
            alert("Error: password must contain at least one number (0-9)!");
            form.pwd1.focus();
            return false;
        }
        re = /[a-z]/;
        if (!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
            alert("Error: password must contain at least one lowercase letter (a-z)!");
            form.pwd1.focus();
            return false;
        }
        re = /[A-Z]/;
        if (!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
            alert("Error: password must contain at least one uppercase letter (A-Z)!");
            form.pwd1.focus();
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        alert("Error: Please check that you've entered and confirmed your password!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
    }

    alert("You entered a valid password: " + form.pwd1.value);
    return true;
}
```

I am trying to use this code for this html

```
 <form name="hw4Form" action="" autocomplete="off">
<br>
<fieldset name="LoginInfo">
<input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" size="30">
<br>
<br>
Password:
<br>
<input id="pwd1" type="password" name="pwd1" placeholder="password" required="required" size="30">
<span id="pwd1Hint" class="hint">Password is too short (must be at least 8 characters)</span>
<br>
Repeat Password:
<br>
<input id="pwd2" type="password" name="pwd2" placeholder="password" required="required" size="30">
<span id="pwd2Hint" class="hint">Passwords don't match</span>
<br>
<br>
```

I get a error in my code editing software but I cant figure out how to fix it
I also would just like to make sure that this javascript will work for the html

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: http://gyazo.com/308fae82d9c0290c1282d3a49d78359d

Comment: missing ; on statement before column 30

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this line:

```
 if(form.pwd1.value != "" && form.pwd1.value == form
```

should be:

```
 if(form.pwd1.value != "" && form.pwd1.value == form.username.value)) {
```

or something similar to this.

In your html you also need to close your form with `</form>`

Answer (score -1):

I advice u using console.log(form) or other fields to check the js performing process.Or why not use firebug to debug the function.

Comment: the error was missing ; on statement before column 30 but it didnt help any

Comment: unless I am missing something

Comment: are u using IE .Chang it ,using chrome or firefox with firebug to debug.You will see more detail message